# Java serialization with backward compatibility issue of member variable type changes

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I have a serialize class with member variables and this is being written to file , i.e. each record in file represents this class. Later, as per new requirement, one of member variable's type is changed and it works fine with writing to new file. However, when I tried to read the old file( the file which was written before this change) , it throws ClasscastException saying "old data type member can't be assigned to the new one".
For example:
My class structure would be:

```
 Public class MyClass implements Serializable
 {
    Date m_date;
    String m_name;
 }
```

So, this represent one record in the file. 
And then, as per new requirement , I had changed "m_date" variable data type from Date to Custom type(Custom Class, lets say ABC which is also serializable), so class structure becomes now:

```
Public class MyClass implements Serializable
{
   ABC m_date;
   String m_name;
}
```

So, problem I am facing here is, when I try to read old file which has each record of type Date and String , it throws exception on this line of code:

```
while ( ( record = inputStream.readObject() ) != null )
```

So, it clearly indicates that while reading the record, it unables to assign Date type to incompatible type ABC.

My question is : How do I make sure that while reading old file, I can be able to update the type Date to ABC and return the updated record, so update record will have values of types ABC and String?

NOTE: I have already the logic available to change Date type to ABC.

Kindly provide/guide me solution with coding example.

~Thanks.

Comment: Could you check this [article](https://lingpipe-blog.com/2010/05/04/upgrading-java-classes-backward-compatible-serialization/) ?

Comment: Why would you need to do that in first line?

Comment: Read the Javadocs on serialization, this is all explained there.  In short, you will need to check the serialVersionUID to see what version the data was serialized in, and then use special private methods that the deserializer can call (`readResolve` I believe) to do conversions.

Comment: I have to read the old file because it's an requirement to process it in certain scenarios and there is new custom class has been created to replace Date type. However old and new file has serialVersionUID defined as: 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
And, I am not getting any error related to incompatible serial version id after modifying data type.

Comment: @RomaKhomyshyn Your link is both irrelevant, as the OP's class wasn't `Externalizable` to begin with, and poor quality. The very first sentence is incorrect, and the 'marker object' trick is unnecessary: all he needs is `catch (OptionalDataException ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have no choice about this. You must change the class back to the original definition. I would then *add* the new `ABC` type as a new data member with a new name. Or you could provide getters and setters that map the old `m_date` member to the new `ABC` datatype.

Once you have existing serializations, you cannot perform serialization-incompatible changes to the class if you want to continue being able to read the, and changing the type of a non-static non-transient member field is an incompatible change. See the Object Versioning chapter of the Java Serialization Specification.